# How to give border radius in Bar chart react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, bar-chart, react-native-chart-kit

I am trying to give space in chart and number and wants to make bar chat curve from top
Like there in number coming on top of chart I have to give space on that and make the chart curve from top.
Please suggest ,
Thanks

[image]

```
<BarChart
          // style={graphStyle}
          data={!_.isEmpty(graphVal())?graphVal():data}
          width={wp('92%')}
          height={hp('32%')}
          yAxisLabel=""
          chartConfig={chartConfig}
          verticalLabelRotation={0}
          showValuesOnTopOfBars={true}
          withHorizontalLabels={false}
          style={styles.barChat}
          withInnerLines={false}
          fromZero={true}
          withVerticalLabels={20}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

#### In Your chartConfig You Just Need To Add A Simple Line

`chartConfig={ ... , barRadius: 5, }`

Like This

```
chartConfig={
    backgroundGradientFrom: '#000',
    backgroundGradientTo: '#000',
    barPercentage: 1,
    barRadius: 5,   
    color: () => {'#000';},
    labelColor: () => '#000',
}
```

##### barRadius:5

This Make Border Round

[image: ROUND BORDER Bars In React-native-Chart-kit]